# Check user connection while there is a cin function

Tags: c++

Hi today i was trying to constantly check the connectivity of users while there is a cin..

this is the code:

```
while (true)
{
    if (InternetCheckConnection(networkBuffer, FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0) != false)
    {
        while (cin >> userInput)
        {
            cout << "> " << userInput << endl;
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm sure that the problem is cin but i have to check constantly the users connectivity (also while there is a cin in progress).

. . .

some people, here (on stackoverflow), told me to use threads... only that I did not know how to solve this problem using them. So i tried this method

```
void test()
{
    if (InternetCheckConnection(networkBuffer, FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0) != false
    {
        cout << "success" << endl;
    } else {
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread first;
    cout << "1: " << first.joinable() << endl;

    first = thread(test);
    cout << "2: " << first.joinable() << endl;

    string s;
    cin >> s;

    first.join();
    cout << "3: " << first.joinable() << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

But the only problem with this code is that he check before the cin and not while there is the cin.

Thanks.

Comment: Why must you constantly check the internet connection while waiting for user input?

Comment: i don't have to check constantly the internet connection while waiting for user input. I have to check constantly also while the user is writing something on the cin.

Comment: OK, why do you have to check for internet connection while the user is typing?  That doesn't seem like something you would need to do and would be pretty wasteful.

Comment: I need this because when someone who uses the program should not have the possibility to use the program without internet connection (both at boot and when he is using it)

Comment: I think you might be better served by just checking for internet connectivity when the user actually applies an action.  If you don't have it then tell them they can't proceed.

Comment: RTFM! `InternetCheckConnection()` is the wrong tool to begin with since it is depreciated `InternetCheckConnection()` does not work in environments that use a web proxy server to access the Internet.

Comment: According to MSDN: `InternetCheckConnection` does not work in environments that use a web proxy server to access the Internet. Depending on the environment, use `NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile` or the NLM Interfaces to check for Internet access instead